# Pascal Triangle array not showing in HTML? How do i solve it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<head> 
  <title> Pascal’s Triangle  </title>

</head>   

<body> 
  <header>
    <div id="strong"> Pascal’s Triangle </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div>  
      <span id="enter"> Please enter any number: </span><input id="number"  /> <br id="screen"/>

      <button id="button" onclick="createPascalTriangle()"> Check   &#187;</button> 
    </div>  <br/>

  </div>
    <div id="show"> </div>



  <footer>
    <div> &copy;Technical Challenge </div>
  <footer>

  <script>
  function createPascalTriangle () {
  var pascalTriangle = [];
  var numRows = document.getElementById("number").value;

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) { 
    pascalTriangle[i] = new Array(i+1);

    for (var j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {            
      if (j === 0 || j === i) {
        pascalTriangle[i][j] = 1;
      } else {
        pascalTriangle[i][j] = pascalTriangle[i-1][j-1] + pascalTriangle[i-1][j];
      }
    }
  }

  return pascalTriangle;

  pascal = JSON.Stringify(pascalTriangle);


document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = pascal;

}  


  </script> 

</body>
```

Pascal Triangle array not displaying in expected 'div'
How do i display these array of Pascal Triangle in HTML?
Here is my code. The 'div 'is not displaying anything
i tried the innerHTML property. the pascalTriangle output is an Array. But i'm unable to display the output in html

Comment: You use `return` in your function before adding elements to the HTML. this will exit the function before executing the operations.

Comment: You have two errors:
1) everything after `return pascalTriangle` is not executed, because a return sets the end of a function. So the JSON and the innerHTML functions are never reached. Move your `return` to the end of the function.
Problem 2): `JSON.Stringify` should be `JSON.stringify` (lowercase s)

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/d7x3e06f/

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be:

1. its `JSON.stringify` (capitalization)
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify
2. You are doing actions after your function returns a value. The function stops being executed as soon as the return statement is reached. You should write at the end of the function:

   ```
   pascal = JSON.stringify(pascalTriangle);
   document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = pascal;
   return pascalTriangle;
   ```

Comment: How can i make each array begin on a new line;

Comment: @AssuranceFemi what do you mean?